Survey123 Connect - Trying to understand the scope of a mobile app crash caused by the "World Street Map" basemap

New to this app, new to a job managing Survey123 apps for field surveyors, and trying to solve some consistent application crashes our field personnel are reporting. After extensive testing, I've isolated the cause to be from a faulty basemap. For some reason, "Survey123 Connect" is assigning all our forms to use a basemap called "World Steet Map" for the geopoint question and Inbox "Map" tab. If you go to the basemap selector and choose something else, "World Street Map" vanishes from the selector, and the user can't ever go back to "World Street Map" for that form again. Once the form is no longer operating off "World Street Map", the mobile application (at least for our entirely iOS users) won't consistently crash after viewing a map panel a specific number of times. So, I've been switching our surveys to use the seemingly-identical "Streets" basemap instead, which avoids these (iOS exclusive?) crashes. In other words, if the user never alters the basemap selector while creating the survey, the resulting form WILL use "World Street Map", and our users WILL eventually crash (no clue if this applies to Android users, though).
While the crashes aren't a problem for us now, I've still got questions to help me understand the scope and scale of this. I want to know if this is just a consequence of something being configured wrong when our organization was setting up Survey123 here, or if this in fact applies to everyone.

Is this default basemap selection something totally controlled by ESRI? Or could organizations have reconfigured what basemap options display there? In other words - is it possible someone on our side just set the wrong basemap entirely as the default while setting things up? For context, our base map selector has 30 options (not counting the vanishing "World Street Map")
If the basemap choices are configurable - is there some way I can see what the Survey123 CURRENT default basemap option would be for any new users? Namely, if it's set to "World Street Map" instead of one of the other (non-crashing) basemap choices?
Can someone with access to Survey123 Connect test creating a new survey through the Connect app (you don't have to actually publish it), then go to the "Map" tab, and then open the basemap selector - Is it defaulting you to "World Street Map" like the image at the top of this post shows? Is "Streets" also on there? If you select "Streets", does "World Steet Map" then vanish from the selector?

Note: I'm not asking about anything regarding the Survey123 web designer, or surveys loaded through the browser. This issue doesn't exist there. Not talking about any custom non-ESRI-created basemaps, either. I'm purely asking about default settings for "Survey123 Connect" created surveys, and the impact it apparently has on the mobile app. And yes, I've reported this to ESRI. But if this turns out to just be from a mistake we made during configuration, I can probably just close the ticket. If it does apply to everyone, then I’ll probably escalate it.
If you are seeing "World Street Map", and want the test case to confirm crashing for yourself, just let me know what mobile device you'd be testing on, and I'll write up a test case (the less RAM a device has, the faster it should crash). I'd be especially curious to know if Android users could crash, too..
